# Generic function with proper signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, generics, parameters

I don't know how to declare second parameter of function boom to have proper type checking, I mean if somebody is sending to function boom first parameter as "foo1" then the second parameter should be only possible as: `(number) => void`. If "foo2" then `(string) => void`.

```js
interface MyFoo {
    foo1: (number) => void;
    foo2: (string) => void;
}

class Bar<Foo> {
    public boom<T extends Foo, K extends keyof MyFoo>(first: K,
        ...args: Parameters<T[K] /* here I don't know how to declare this parameter */){

    }
}

new Bar<MyFoo>().boom("foo1", /* callback with signature: (number) => void */)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that [parameter names in function types are required](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-i-get-type-checking-for-number--string-or-t--t), so this definition must be altered:

```
interface MyFoo {
    foo1: (x: number) => void; 
    foo2: (x: string) => void;
}
```

Now, in `Bar<Foo>` we only need one generic parameter `K` on the `boom()` method, since the type `Foo` will be specified for us.  I don't fully understand your use case, since it looks like *maybe* you want `boom()` to take a variable number of parameters, but this doesn't match the comment about how you need a callback function.  So I assume that `boom()` takes two parameters: a key name and a callback function:

```
class Bar<Foo> {
    public boom<K extends keyof Foo>(first: K, second: Foo[K]) { }
}
```

And then here's how you use it:

```
// okay, the callback is (x: number) => void
new Bar<MyFoo>().boom("foo1", (x: number) => console.log(x.toFixed(2)));

// error, the callback is (x: number) => void but should be (x: string) => void
new Bar<MyFoo>().boom("foo2", (x: number) => console.log(x.toFixed(2)));
```

By the way, this doesn't stop you from using an interface with non-function properties:

```
interface MyFoo { age: number }
new Bar<MyFoo>().boom("age", 40); // okay
```

If you require that `boom()` only work on keys corresponding to function-like properties, you will need some fancier [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types):

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> =
    Extract<keyof T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]>;

class Bar<Foo> {
    public boom<K extends KeysMatching<Foo, Function>>(first: K, second: Foo[K]) { }
}

// okay, the callback is (x: number) => void
new Bar<MyFoo>().boom("foo1", (x: number) => console.log(x.toFixed(2)));

// error, the callback is (x: number) => void but should be (x: string) => void
new Bar<MyFoo>().boom("foo2", (x: number) => console.log(x.toFixed(2))); 

interface MyFoo { age: number }

// error, "age" is not accepted anymore
new Bar<MyFoo>().boom("age", 40); // error
```

Hope that helps you.  Good luck!